# Маршрут в виде стрелочек

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Нужно проложить маршрут по переданным координатам в виде стрелочек.

Нашел пример - http://jsfiddle.net/e_neko/e83nt8j5/

```
ymaps.modules.require(['geoObject.Arrow'], function (Arrow) {
        var arrow = new Arrow([[52.7, 37.0],[50.733835, 38.788227],[52.733835, 38.788227],[55.733835, 39.788227], [57.733835, 38.788227] ], null, {
            geodesic: true,
            strokeWidth: 5,
            opacity: 0.5,
            strokeStyle: 'shortdash'
        });
        myMap.geoObjects.add(arrow);
    });
```

Работает нормально, но мне помимо этого нужно передавать ballonContent для каждой стрелки. Это можно как-то сделать?

Еще есть пример на Яндексе - https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/arrow
Тут можно насоздавать много new Arrow() со своим balloonContent, но это немного глючит если стрелок много, не уверен что это правильно.

Стрелок может быть много - например тысяча.

Comment: Можете код показать?

Comment: https://codepen.io/roman-sarwarow/pen/YzXZrvJ

Вот в таком варианте я знаю как задать balloonContent для каждой стрелки, но жутко глючит.

Comment: https://codepen.io/roman-sarwarow/pen/bGdqoxG в таком варианте не глючит, но не понимаю как задать balloonContent

Comment: Возможно, я не понял задачу, но если задать balloonContent стандартно для Polyline (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/GeoObject-docpage/#GeoObject__param-feature.properties ), у меня получается задавать и изменять содержимое балуна. Вот пример: https://jsfiddle.net/naivv/vorLbmct/ (это ваш второй пример, я только добавил настройку содержимого балуна и необязательный обработчик клика мышью). Проверьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: спасибо за ответ!
BalloonContent должен быть уникальным для каждой стрелки.
Т.е. по каждой стрелке нужно передать координаты и собственный balloonContent (у меня это будет время). В вашем примере получается на какую стрелку не тыкни везде одно сообщение будет показано.

Comment: Насколько я понял ваш код, это одна фигура. Соответственно, настройка балуна тоже одна. Однако сообщение выводится разное - посмотрите, в обработчике клика я меняю содержимое балуна, там показываются координаты щелчка. Вы можете задавать свое содержимое. Также можно открывать балун без привязки к геообъекту (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_and_hint ). Также обратите внимание, что в общем случае активный балун на карте может быть только один.